# Passing the score result of my quiz game to other activity where it will be computed with a circular bar to show its percentage

Tags: android-progressbar

I am new to android programming. I'm having a trouble on how am I going to implement circular progress bar using Thread(new Runnable) with condition based on the result of the quiz game I have developed. What I want to happen is, that when the quiz finishes, it will go to next activity where the progress bar is and it will show the percentageof what I got from the quiz. So far, i havr already made the progress bar, but I can't use if else statement on it to put condition for every score, because when i do and run it, it always shows 0% no matter what the score is. Help me please, this is my project in school. Thanks in advance.